# Is there a way to mask a sticky element using an absolute element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to create a sticky position image that changes as it scrolls across the border between two sections of my page. So basically, there should be two sticky position images, the top one gets masked by the bottom section and the bottom gets masked by the top section. I am having trouble figuring out a way to mask both images at the same time (you can use the bottom section `div` to hide the top image, and vice versa, but not both at the same time).

[Here's an image to illustrate what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALSiv.jpg)

Here's the code I'm using:

```css
.lblue {
    height: 40vh;
    width:10vw;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top:30vh;
    left:45vw;
    background:lightblue;
}

.lred {
    height: 40vh;
    width:10vw;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top:30vh;
    left:45vw;
    background:lightcoral;
}

.blue {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height:150vh;
    width:100vw;
    background:blue;
}

.red {
    position: absolute;
    top:100vh;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="blue">
        <div class="lblue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="red">
        <div class="lred"></div>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a solution. The trick is to use the images as CSS backgrounds, because CSS backgrounds can be easily fixed in the viewport of their parents.

```css
.blue {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height:150vh;
    width:100vw;

    background: blue fixed linear-gradient(lightblue, lightblue) 45vw 30vh / 10vw 40vh no-repeat;
}

.red {
    position: absolute;
    top:100vh;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100vw;

    background: red fixed linear-gradient(lightcoral, lightcoral) 45vw 30vh / 10vw 40vh no-repeat;

}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

In this solution, you can replace `linear-gradient(color, color)` by the URL of your image, using `url(https://…)`. I used gradients because, for the browser, gradients are (generated) images. So, this trick actually works with images.

The `position: absolute` also becomes useless, at least for the demo.

The long `background` rule may need some explanations. [`background` is a shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) (= a short way to write several properties in a single line) for:

```css
background-color: red;
background-attachement: fixed;
background-image: linear-gradient(lightcoral, lightcoral);
background-position: 45vw 30vh;
background-size: 10vw 40vh;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score -1):

`position:fixed` can do this if you conside a `clip-path` trick to hide the overflow so that each element will show only inside its section

```css
.lblue,
.lred {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 10vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 45vw;
  background: lightblue;
}

.lred {
  background: lightcoral;
}

.blue,
.red {
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0); /* this is important */
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

body {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <div class="lblue"></div>
</div>
<div class="red">
  <div class="lred"></div>
</div>
```